# Correct Video for lens distortion in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, video, image-processing, matlab-cvst, distortion

I have a video that was taken with a GoPro and I would like to get rid of the fisheye distortion. I know I can get rid of the fisheye with the gopro software, but I want to do this using Matlab instead.

I know there's this http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/undistortimage.html that applies for images, however, how would I apply it for a full video? The number of frames in the video 207 (it's like 5 - 6 second short video).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just sample your video stream at 24fp (using e.g. ffmpeg, see [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=21190) ), apply your Matlab routine one frame at a time, then rebuild the video stream in Matlab itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `undistortImage` to each frame of the video.  If the video is saved to a file, you can use `vision.VideoFileReader` to read it one frame at a time, and then you call `undistortImage`.  Then you can write the undistorted frame to a different file using `vision.VideoFileWriter`, or you can display it using `vision.VideoPlayer`.

Of course, this is all assuming that you have calibrated your camera beforehand using the Camera Calibrator App.